# Syntax error or access violation error in php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Table name: `cms_user_table`

**I create login code with php PDO.**

**But This shows me error of Access Violation in my query. Please help me to resolve this.**

Below is my error:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id,username,password,psalt from cms_user_table WHERE username ='raj'' at line 1 in C:\wamp\www\pdo\bhaskarcms\includes\db.php on line 286
```

Below is my login code:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/config.php');    
$database = new db("root", "", "localhost", "bhaskar_hindi_dbs", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{       
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];         
    $sql = $database->getRows("id,username,password,psalt from cms_user_table WHERE username =:username",array(':username'=>$username));
    foreach ($sql as $r) {
        $u=$r['username'];
        $p=$r['password'];
        $p_salt=$r['psalt'];
        $id=$r['id'];
    }                
    $site_salt="bhaskarhindisalt";
    $salted_hash = hash('sha256',$password.$site_salt.$p_salt);
    if($p==$salted_hash) {
        $_SESSION['Auth']['id']= $id;
        header("Location:state.php");
    }   
    else {
        echo "<h2>Username/Password is Incorrect.</h2>";
    }
}                       
?>
```

**The getRows function is created in db class** and I call this function in my login code and passing parameters.

```
public function getRows($query, $params=array()) {
    try{ 
        $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute($params);
        return $stmt->fetchAll();       
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    }       
}
```

Comment: You have an invalid query. Try writing a proper `select` statement and you should be fine. `SELECT id,username,password,psalt from cms_user_table WHERE username =:username`

Comment: `foo FROM bar` is not the same as `SELECT foo FROM bar`. You completely forgot the SELECT part.

Comment: ok thanks sorry i think its my typing mistake..thank you for highlighting.....thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss the `select` statement at beginning of your string:

```
$sql = $database->getRows("select id,username,password,psalt from cms_user_table WHERE username =:username",array(':username'=>$username));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$sql = $database->getRows("SELECT id,username,password,psalt from cms_user_table WHERE username =:username",array(':username'=>$username));
```

Comment: I know you're trying to show emphasis because it was missing, but putting the asterisks in a code block when they don't belong there is a bad idea, and it makes your code invalid.